# How to store data-* attributes in <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have some javascript that I load in my head.  And I want to reference some data attributes.

```
  <meta id="pendo_data" data-user-id="<%= current_user&.id %>"
       data-user-email="<%= current_user&.email %>"
       data-account-id="<%= current_account&.id %>"
       data-account-name="<%= current_account&.name %>"
  />
```

Then in the javascript I can do:

`$(#'pendo_data').data('user-id')`

`<meta>` seems like the wrong tag for this.  `<div>`s are not allowed in `<head>`.

What is the best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing # `$('#pendo_data')`, aren't you?

Comment: If you don't know where to put it in the head it is because it is not being used there. The data attributes should be set on the elements that need that info. I would go with this approach. Also check the jQuery data() function because there are times that you are better using jQuery attr() for the same purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them on the `<html>` element if you need them in the head. That way they're there immediately for your script and you don't need to mess with using elements outside their intended use.

The `<html>` element is accessed via `document.documentElement`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html data-user-id="<%= current_user&.id %>"
      data-user-email="<%= current_user&.email %>"
      data-account-id="<%= current_account&.id %>"
      data-account-name="<%= current_account&.name %>" >
  <head>
    <script>
    for (const p in document.documentElement.dataset) {
      console.log(`${p} = ${document.documentElement.dataset[p]}`)
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: that seems like that is a good solution. what are your thoughts on putting it on either the head or the enclosing script tag?

Comment: @Jonathan: I thought about the head at first, but I think there were some legacy browsers that didn't make that element available until after it was closed. Also for the sake of legacy, you'd need to select by tag name, since `document.head` wasn't always supported. As to the `script` element, that would work I think, but it's again a matter of selecting by tag name and grabbing the last match, which *should* be the currently executing one. I'd prefer the `<html>` myself.

Comment: Note: for now I am putting it on the `<script>` tag.  It works.  I like having it closer to the implementation.  Easier to have it in a partial / component.

Comment: @Jonathan: Sounds good, especially for cases where you need different data for different scripts. Also take note of what Juan wrote above. Using `.data()` is often not best as it just duplicates the data in jQuery's cache, often for no reason.