# Data attributes in head and meta tags

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49089411/4746087), I want to dynamically change and translate the values of some `head` tags (`title`, `meta description`, `meta keywords` ...) based on a chosen language by the user. It's a `node.js` application where I'm using `Express` and `ejs` to inject the language.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title data-translate-key="title">Translated title</title> 
    <meta name="description" data-translate-key="description" content="Translated description">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this allowed, and is this valid html? [This document](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/global-attributes.html) on w3docs.com says the following:

> Allows private information to be exchanged between HTML and its DOM representation. It gives the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

I ran the above snippet in the official [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and it did not show any errors. So therefore I assumed it is valid html. However I cannot find much information about it.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about it apparently it can be applied on all HTML elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is **valid**.

As stated in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*):

> The `data-*` **global attributes** form a class of attributes called custom data attributes, that allow proprietary information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation by scripts.

`data-*` attributes are **global attributes** and global attributes as stated in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes):

> Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can be used on all elements, though they may have no effect on some elements.

can be applied to all elements.